a single YAML pipeline file that resides in the default branch (typically main or master),
a single YAML pipeline file that resides in the default branch (typically main or master), and configure it to trigger on pushes to any branch in your repository.
trigger:
branches:
include:
- '*'
i have added this but it's not working
My Pipeline should reside in main branch and whenever thr is push to any branch pipeline which resides in main branch should get trigger
